# Sum of a 3-card set probability

Tags: probability

For a given set of 3-card combination, the sum from each set can range from 3 to 30 (i.e., 1 + 1 + 1 = 3 and 10 + K + Q = 30; where ace counts as 1, and 10 and face cards count as 10).

I want to develop 3-card combinatoric probability formulas representing the sum of 3 to 30 from single deck and multi-deck of cards.  I need an example for any one set sum, and from your example I will then apply the same logic for other sets.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: This is an incredibly tedious and laborious process if we were to draw from the deck without replacement.  If we were to draw with replacement it becomes easy to do with generating functions: $(x+x^2+\dots+x^9+4x^{10})^3/13^3$, the coefficient of $x^k$ in the expansion of the generating function is the probability that the sum of the values of the three cards is exactly $k$.  Note that the probabilities will vary between these examples.  In the question with replacement the probability the sum is three is $\frac{1}{13^3}$ and without replacement is $\frac{4\cdot 3\cdot 2}{52\cdot 51\cdot 50}$

Comment: For sum of 3 w/o replacement, there is only one 1-1-1 combination, so the equation would be COMBIN(4,3)/COMBIN(52,3).  This equation yields the same answer as your (4*3*2)/(52*51*50), which is 0.000181.